# On finding the volume using triple integral

Tags: calculus, volume, multiple-integral

Find the volume of the cylinder with base as disk of unit radius in the $xy$ plane centered at $(1,1,0)$ and top being the surface $z=[(x-1)^2+(y-1)^2]^{3/2}$

According to me it should be

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1\int_0^{r^3}r  dzdrd\theta$$
Am I right?

Comment: seems right to me!

Comment: It's not a cylinder, the top is curved not a circular plane.

Comment: Yes, That's correct.

Using : 

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
x=1+rcos\theta\\
y=1+rsin\theta\\
z=z
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

$\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{r^3}rdzdrd\theta=\frac{2}{5}\pi$